# length of 'digital' recurring expansion of rational number

Tags: recreational-mathematics

Here's a question of a 'recreational' nature.

A similar question has already been posed for radix 10 in particular:
[Integer division: the length of the repetitive sequence after the decimal point](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/900/integer-division-the-length-of-the-repetitive-sequence-after-the-decimal-point) .
My question has been partly answered there; however, I'd be interested in anything further that can be added.

Suppose you have a rational number $n/d$ in simplest terms and a radix $r \ge 2$. Are there any results on the cycle length $l$ of the recurring part, and less importantly on the length of the *prefix* (numerals between the decimal point and the start of the recurring section)?

One result is that $l|d-1$.

I wonder whether there are simple results for various cases:

- $r$ is a prime $p$ (such as $2$)
- $r$ is a prime power $p^k$ (such as $16=2^4$)
- $r$ is square-free (such as $10 = 2 \cdot 5$), i.e. $r$ is a product of *distinct* primes, i.e $p^2|r$ for *no* prime $p$

Comment: l divides the totient of d, which doesn't necessarily divide d-1.  In any case, the form of r is irrelevant, since the answer only depends on the value of r mod d.

Answer (score 1):

Write $d=2^p 5^q m$, where $(m,10)=1$. Then the length of the prefix of $n/d$ is $\max(p,q)$. (That's for base 10, of course.)